# printing a loop in tkinter do while loop with delay

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to print a do while loop in a tkinter gui. While a use a `time.sleep(0.5)` the loop prints out site the gui in the python shell. How can I print the loop with delay in the gui?
Here is the code. Thanks in advance.

```py
import time

import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk


#********************************************  DO WHILE TOT 10  
def dowhiletien():

    window = Toplevel()
    window.geometry('400x300+370+400')
    window.configure(bg='#511c35')
    window.title('Do While:   do while tot 10')


    def startloop():
        x = 1
    
        while(x <= 10):

            mnumlabel = tk.Label(window, bg="#511c35", fg="#d7ebba", font=("Arial",12), text= x )
            mnumlabel.pack(padx= 10)    
            print(x)
            x = x+1

#   --------------------------------------------  Button voor starten loop
    stop_button = tk.Button(window, text="Start Loop", bg="#FFA630", font=("Arial",12), 
    fg="#D7EBBA",  activebackground='#511c35',width=10, height=1,
    command=startloop).pack(side = TOP)

    
#   --------------------------------------------  Button voor stoppen  
    stop_button = tk.Button(window, text="Stopen", bg="#FFA630", font=("Arial",12), fg="#D7EBBA",  
    activebackground='#511c35',width=10, height=1,
    command=window.destroy).pack(side = BOTTOM)


#***********************************************  MAIN WINDOW  
    
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.configure(bg='#511c35')
        self.title('Do While:   main menu')
        self.geometry("460x360") # breed, Hoog

#       ------------------------------------- Mainmenu Botton voor nieuwe list maken 
        # Button voor list maken
        maaklist_button = tk.Button(self, text="do while tot 10", bg="#FFA630", 
        activebackground='#511c35', font=("Arial",14), fg="#D7EBBA", width=15, height=1,
        command=dowhiletien).grid(row=2, column=0, padx= 10, pady= 10)
        
        maaklistlabel = tk.Label(self, bg="#511c35", fg="#D7EBBA",font=("Arial",14), text=" Do 
        while tot 10").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w', padx= 10, pady= 10)

#       ------------------------------------ Mainmenu Botton voor stoppen en verlaten app 
        # Button voor stoppen
        exit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Stoppen", bg="#DC143C", activebackground='#90EE90', 
        font=("Arial",14), fg="#000000", width=15, height=1,
        command=self.destroy).grid(row=7, column=0, padx= 10, pady= 10)
        exitlabel = tk.Label(self, bg="#511c35", fg="#D7EBBA", font=("Arial",14), text="Stop en 
        verlaat aplicatie").grid(row=7, column=1, sticky='w', padx= 10, pady= 10)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't use `sleep()` in your gui code. Have you considered using the `after()` method?

Comment: Hello mr. Quarana, yes i have tried that but then the do while keeps looping in the python shell

Comment: one method is to use `after()` instead of both `while+sleep` - and `after(mlilliseconds, function)` will work as loop which repeate `function` instead of `while`, and it will do it with delays (`mlilliseconds`) instead of `sleep`. Second method is to use `window.update()` in `while`-loop and it will force `mainloop` to update all widgets in window - and this way it will add your `Label` before end of loop.